# How to bind Java object to Javascript control

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, binding

I am using the [Sencha framework](http://www.sencha.com/) and am creating controls using Javascript. I want to fetch some data from the database using Java, but am uncertain on how to bind that Java object to the Sencha-created controls. What can I try?

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading API documentation and guides!

Answer (score 0):

'Sencha created controls'? 
Check Sencha API for the controls - checkbox, gridpanel etc..

You may need to use a store config in most cases.

Comment: I have fetched the data from database in jsp..now want to bind it to javascript controls which are created using sencha framework..

Comment: You cannot bind java objects with javascript. You could do only by passing the output in JSON/XML formats

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Sencha GXT](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/): "Sencha GXT is the fastest, most powerful way to create rich web-based applications using Java."

Comment: Is there any other way...i have seen only json data is binded with javascript control...how to do it for java objects?

Comment: Create Java Servlet (working under TomCat). Servlet contains get and post methods, use Get method for get JSON. Load this json using data store, associated with control. But all this exists in Sencha GXT

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to create a combobox in sencha, then do it as:

```
var javaData = = [
       [1, 'item1']
      ,[2, 'item2']
  ];
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
     id:0
    ,fields:
        [
            'myId',   //numeric value is the key
            'myText' //the text value is the value
        ]
    ,data: javaData
})
,valueField:'myId'
,displayField:'myText'
,mode:'local'
```

});

replace javaData var value with your data from server.
Ensure that the data is in json format to run this example.

For more: http://www.sencha.com/learn/combobox-faq/

Answer (score 0):

What your ExtJS store does is an Ajax call to a certain page on your java application. That page will return data formatted in JSON so that your ExtJS store can parse that data.

Basically it doesn't mather what your back end technology is. You just need to make sure your page returns json in the following format:

```
{
   data: [], //Array of json data
   success: true, //true when your call was handled succesfull
   total: 10 //The total items of a certain object
}
```

So in your case your JSP page will display the result in the JSON format as explained above, your ExtJS store will be configured to call that certain JSP page.